# Construct an Object of type determined at runtime?

Tags: java, reflection

So I'm trying to test the methods on a certain class (with a default constructor), and the test methods can only be `public` and of type `void`, and must start with "test".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> c = null;
    c = Class.forName(args[0]);

    System.out.println(c.getName());
    for (Method m : c.getMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().startsWith("test")
                && m.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE)
                && m.getModifiers() == Modifier.PUBLIC) {

            Object o = null;

            try {
                o = c.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

            // ???    
        }
    }
}
```

So, my checks work, but I do not know how to make a new instance of the class and test the method. How would I do this?

Comment: What do you think `c.newInstance();` does?

Comment: I want to cast that to the class I'm using, and use the method `m` from it.

Comment: So, cast it, or use reflection to call the method...

Comment: How would I cast it? That's my question.

Comment: Why do you need to cast anything? You're using reflection all the way through.

Comment: To use the method `m` in the loop.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how reflection works. Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). Then read the javadoc for `Method`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
m.invoke(o);
```

This will *reflectively* invoke your method ´m´, given it doesn't receive any arguments.

One note about checking if the method is `public`. You'd better perform that check this way:

```
boolean isPublic = Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers());
```

Unless you want to check that the method is **only** public and has no other modifier, in which case your code is OK.

Exception handling left as an excersice ;)